# angular-ui-swiper: swiper is not defined

Tags: angularjs, slider

I am using the angular-ui-swiper and I want to set the active slide depending on the URL-Parameter. I have an angular controller, where the data is loaded for the swiper. This works fine, the buttons are working (prev, next). I call the method slideTo to set the activeslider after link click in the navigation. But it is not working if I load the page with the special parameter. The swiper-instance is not defined. So I have to call the correct page lifecycle event. I used the load, init-events, an equivalent to document ready, but without any success. It is only working if I put my setActiveSlide-Method to the scroll-event :D

Do you have any idea?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to make the  set the activeslider in this kind of block:

```
 angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    //code here
});
```

Can you make a jsfiddle so we can see your code?